# What are the benefits of System.Configuration over XMLSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization, configuration

When i want to save configurations, i usually use the XMLSerializer. It's easy to use and understandable. At the end, you just cast a deserialized object to a certain type. Thats it. Perfect.

Now i have to learn the whole System.Configuration-thing and neither do i know where to start, nor what it exactly does. Just a lot of stuff with "Sections", "mappings" and whatnot. How do i handle this? MSDN-Articles are, again, not explanatory of what i am doing with this. It just seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead for doing a very simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about custom sections in the application configuration class? [here it is described when derived from MS Configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Also it is possible to define your own custom configuration section handler [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309045) that will take XML and deserialize it to some class value

Please ask more specific question if you would like to get more specific answer

UPD
To load from config file when you've derived from ConfigurationSection you can use code like below

```
Configuration config;
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var _current = (ClassSettings)config.GetSection(sectionName);
```

If you've used custom configuration section handler (IConfigurationSectionHandler) you can load class instance using code like this one:

```
var database = (DatabaseSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(databaseSettingsName);
```

Writing to configuration file much more tricky unfortunately.

MS suggests [this way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b865ce7a-6616-4109-90a5-553efc928075/modify-connectionstring-in-appconfig?forum=csharpgeneral) to update configuration file content

Or you can open configuration file like any other XML document and have updated it like any other XML document:

```
XmlDocument config = new XmlDocument();
string configName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config";
config.Load(configName);
XmlNode databaseNode = config.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(sectionName + "/" + DatabaseName);
if (databaseNode != null)
{
    databaseNode.Attributes[Database.PasswordName].Value = value.Database.PasswordEnc;
}
//another nodes changes are skipped
config.Save(configName);
```

However you can use Protect section method to encrypt section in the configuration file:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
ConfigurationSection section = config.Sections[sectionName];
if (section != null)
{
    var info = section.SectionInformation;
    var pr = info.IsProtected;
    if (pr)
        info.UnprotectSection();
    res = GetSettingsSection<T>(sectionName, value);
    if (!pr)
    {
        info.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

Also it is possible to open configuration file like XML, serialize your settings class instance and replace old element (config section) with new one.

Unfortunately I can't say that there are a lot of benefits by using MS app.config style. This is one more abstraction layer and some additional functionality (protect/unprotect section loading file from user or machine store and so on.

For ASP applications configuration files are combined - maching web.config settings can be expanded with app web.config.

For small winforms app I prefer to use JSON serialized config file - it doesn't contain any overhead like MS app.config and have no XMLSerializer issues (like with performance)

Comment: I know that already. What i don't understand is: How i save a configuration file. How i load one. And why should i use all that over the much simpler XMLSerializer?

Comment: It doesn't work. OpenExeConfiguration don't accept strings. It want's some FileMap-classes. Initializing those with Assembly.Location or Application.Location don't work either. It says, the fileLocation is empty.

Comment: @user2762996 I've shown you part of production code. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms224437(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that it accepts string in .NET 3.5 and 4